Splitting and substitution by comma is not working in shell script
I have a string
z="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"

Now I want the data in the below format:
job_name=market_scenario
channel=GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM
time_limit=60sec

I am doing the below processing:
z="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"
IFS=","
read -ra arr <<< "$z"
env=''
job_name=''
channel=''
time_limit=''
for val in "${arr[@]}";
do
    split_value=$(echo $val | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}')
    if [[  $val =~ "job_name=" ]];
        then
            job_name=$split_value
    elif [[ $val =~ "time_limit=" ]];
        then
            time_limit=$split_value
    elif [[ $val =~ "channel=" ]];
        then
           temp_data=$split_value
           channel=$(echo "$temp_data" | awk '{ gsub (" ", ",", $0); print}')
    fi
done

echo $job_name
echo $time_limit
echo $channel

I am getting output for channel
GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM

The spaces are not getting replace by a comma.
I am new to shell scripting and unable to fix this issue.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

Normally when someone posts a question that starts with an input string like z="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec" it's because in their real code they actually have a surrounding loop like while read z; do ....; done that's populating z iteratively for multiple lines. Is that what you have? If so, see why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Do you REALLY just want the 3 lines of output you show or do you actually want to populate 3 shell variables named based on the tags in the input as if the "output" you show had been executed? If the latter then is there any reason to use 3 separate tag variables for this, e.g. job_name=market_scenario, instead of an associative array indexed by the tags, e.g. t2v[job_name]=market_scenario, so your code that parses the input can be independent of the tag values from the input?

IFS=, read -ra kvs <<<"$z"

for kv in "${kvs[@]}"; do
    case $kv in
        channel=*)
            declare "${kv// /,}"
            ;;
        job_name=*|time_limit=*)
            declare "$kv"
            ;;
    esac
done


split on comma (without permanently changing IFS)
select desired assignments

replace spaces with commas if appropriate
perform the assignments



If spaces should be replaced with commas everywhere, not just in channel, then another option is:
IFS=, read -ra kvs <<<"$z"

for kv in "${kvs[@]}"; do
    [[ $kv =~ ^(job_name|channel|time_limit)= ]] &&
    declare "${kv// /,}"
done


The reason for your incorrect output has already been given in another answer (field splitting is performed on expansion of unquoted parameters). Two rules of thumb that would have avoided the problem:

Always double-quote variable use (unless you know you shouldn't)
Don't permanently modify IFS (unless you know you should)

(Quoting variable use in case $v in, [[ $v =~ ..., and a=$b is not required but is safe.)

BTW, if you don't want to assign variables (you just want to print the entire string (whatever it contains) with substitutions):

bash: tr ', ' '\n,' <<<"$z"
POSIX shell: printf "%s\n" "$z" | tr ', ' '\n,'


if it is known that z contains only desired assignments (input is trusted), and spaces should be replaced everywhere: IFS=, read -ra kvs <<<"$z"; declare "${kvs[@]// /,}"

an example of unsafe input could be as simple as z=a=b,c=d,PATH=/my/bin/dir - no special characters, but if blindly assigned, now attacker may be able to subvert any subsequent external binary callout in the program

As declare work like eval, have a look at my answer (which should be quicker ;-)

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub declare does not work like eval or source: var=v='$(date) !@#$%^&*"'; declare "$var"; declare -p v; eval "$var"; source /dev/stdin <<<"$var". I thought already commented somewhere that quickest for completely trusted input is: IFS=, read -ra kvs <<<"$z"; declare "${kvs[@]// /,}" - but completely trusted user input is not normal - trust but verify

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub d'oh! it was my first comment here!

I have a string
z="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"

Now I want the data in the below format:
job_name=market_scenario
channel=GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM
time_limit=60sec

You might use GNU AWK for this task following way
z="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"
echo "$z" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=",";OFS=","}{$1=$1;print}'

which gives output
job_name=market_scenario
channel=GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM
time_limit=60sec

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that , is row separator (RS) and , is output row separator (ORS). For each line I do $1=$1 to trigger line rebuilt and print changed line. If you want to know more about RS or ORS read 8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

FYI there's nothing GNU-specific in this answer, it'll behave the same way in any awk.

No need for the rococo, bash can do this pretty straight.
#!/bin/bash
z="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"
IFS=,
for var in $z; do
    echo "${var// /,}"
done

and as @jhnc points out you can add a declare "${var// /,}" to get the assignments as well.
Just remember that IFS is applied only on expansion splits, not source readin (and for future reference variable assignments are never split; a=$b doesn't need quoting).

t=${z//,/$'\n'}; echo "${t// /,}"

btw, "not readin splits": read k v <<<"k=v" ; declare -p v vs IFS== read k v <<<"k=v"; declare -p v

@jhnc mmmm, by readin I meant source readin, not the read command's splitting. Bad wording on my part, I'll fix it, thanks for pointing out the ambiguiity.

change echo to declare in your code and you don't need the dangers of source

@jhnc it'd still run command substitution on the value, no?

var='v=$(date)'; declare "$var"; declare -p v ?

@jhnc no, you're right, of course

Try adding unset IFS just before the final echo and see what you get.
Do you understand what's going on now?  The variable was assigned correctly but when you went to display it at the end, the commas were replaced with spaces because of the IFS.
I thought you might be amused by my version:
 z="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"
 IFS=","
 read -ra arr <<< "$z"
 for val in "${arr[@]// /,/}";
 do
     eval "$val"
 done
 IFS=
 echo $job_name
 echo $time_limit
 echo $channel

The variable names are in the z variable and each piece of the string looks like a valid bash assignment, except for the spaces in the channel. In cases like this, bash is happy to do the parsing for you via eval.
We can save a bit of time by doing the substitution in bash rather than calling out to awk, sed or tr.  This is done with the (admittedly quite horrible) "${arr[@]// /,}" says to extract each element from the array, replacing all spaces found with commas.  The double quotes are necessary to keep the channel values from coming up as separate arguments.

Something like this, using Parameter Expansion from bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"

while [[ -n "$var" ]]; do                   ##: Test if $var is not empty.
  first="${var%%,*}"                        ##: Extract the first string sep by a `,' which is job_name=market_scenario
  if [[ "${first}" == 'channel='* ]]; then  ##: If the string starts with `channel=*'
    declare "${first// /,}"                 ##: Replace all spaces with a `,' and do the assignment.
  else
    declare "$first"                        ##: Otherwise just do the normal assignment.
  fi
  rest=${var#*"$first"}                     ##: Remove the first string the ends with a `,'
  var="${rest#,}"                           ##: Remove any leading `,' so var now starts with channel=GOOGLE...
done




Printing/checking the values
printf '%s\n' "$job_name" "$channel" "$time_limit"

Output
market_scenario
GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM
60sec


declare -p job_name channel time_limit

Output
declare -- job_name="market_scenario"
declare -- channel="GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM"
declare -- time_limit="60sec"


If the loadable builtins are available, like csv and dsv, something like
enable csv || exit

var='job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec'

csv -a array "$var"

declare -p array



Or source and Process Substitution. The input should be 100% trusted source, otherwise code injection is just around the corner.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var="job_name=market_scenario,channel=GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec"

IFS=, read -ra array <<< "$var"

source <(printf '%q\n' "${array[@]// /,}")


printf '%s\n' "$job_name" "$channel" "$time_limit"

declare -p job_name channel time_limit



Be careful of the source builtin command see,

help source

source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
    
    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.


Consider the value of z is something like:

z=PATH=/my/bin/dir

Running source against it will change the users default path to something else, in this case /my/bin/dir (By:  @jhnc)

See the Bash Builtins for source and declare


note that quoting isn't sufficient to protect against maliciious injection - consider z=PATH=/my/bin/dir

Another option with any awk, using gsub
% printf "%s" "$z" | awk -v RS="," '{gsub(/ /,",",$0)}1'

The Record Separator RS="," breaks the string into the desired rows and gsub replaces the spaces with comma. Since we don't have a trailing newline we can directly print $0.
output
job_name=market_scenario
channel=GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM
time_limit=60sec


If you trust your strings, get the variables associated with eval
% eval $(printf "%s" "$z" | awk -v RS="," '{gsub(/ /,",",$0)}1')

output
% echo "$job_name\n$channel\n$time_limit" 
market_scenario
GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM
60sec

Make sure to read how to make eval safe if you don't trust your strings.

keep it simple :
printf '%s' 'job_name=market_scenario,channel='\
            'GOOGLE FACEBOOK INSTAGRAM,time_limit=60sec' | 


mawk NF=NF RS=, OFS=,


job_name=market_scenario
channel=GOOGLE,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM
time_limit=60sec

